# Angular app not picked up by github pages?

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

First I setup A records for `canary.fireflysemantics.com`.

Then waited an hour (Not sure if time matters?).

I created a brand new repository:
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/canary/

I then pushed the app using `ng deploy` like this:

```
ng deploy --base-href=https://canary.fireflysemantics.com --cname=canary.fireflysemantics.com
```

And the files are now in the repository `github-pages` branch:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/canary

However they are not being published / built and the CNAME is not being showed as picked up by the UI, so I assume that it is not seen either:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried pushing any changes? After you push the change it will get rebuild.

Comment: Yes I tried that.  It does not work.  In order to get it to work I first have to create the `gh-pages` branch manually and initialize it with a simple `index.html` page.  That will deploy fast.  I can then run the angular command to push the entire Angular app, and then it works.