# Angular App Deployed to Github Pages Not Initializing?

Tags: angular, github, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

[This is related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596143/angular-app-not-picked-up-by-github-pages).

I got the app to be picked up and published by Github Pages by creating the gh-pages branch before running the deploy.

After deploying the app did become available on the domain:

```
https://fsalpha-canary.fireflysemantics.com/
```

The `base` attribute of `index.html` is set to:

```
<base href="https://fsalpha-canary.fireflysemantics.com/">
```

It looks like all the angular resources are loading, however the app is not rendering.

Any ideas?

### Update

I figured this out and I'm leaving the question just for as a reference for others.

When I test locally with `ng serve -o` the app compiles and serves fine.

When I test with `ng serve -o --prod=true` the app says that it compiles successfully, but it does not initialize so all we see is a white screen.  This is not really related to github pages.

Filed a bug report with Angular CLI here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how helpful this is but I've previously had issues with github pages not loading my css files because the path to them changed when going from local to hosted on it. 
I fixed it by modifying the path with just adding or removing a / or ./ in the front of the link. I don't know angular but maybe some path somewhere is changed?

Comment: It was related to the way angular compiles a production app vs a local ahead of time app.  When compiled for production the app stops rendering for some reason.